# Open source to read PSD with vectors

Tags: psd

Is there any library which allows reading PSD with vector paths? E.g. gwenview and gimp seem to rasterize fonts and paths. The same issue with libraries like

https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools

Does PSD has rasterize data for each layer itself or it's just about how libraries work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for text layer - PSD contains both rasterized data and text settings. Therefore, you can use already rendered text or draw your own.

There is also a merged image, which contains render result of all layers but it is optional.

It looks like libpsd has [path support](https://github.com/alco/psdump/blob/master/libpsd-0.9/src/path.c).

Comment: Havn't tested it yet, but seems like it's the best lib we have for now. Thanks!